# Testing - Azure AD, DDoS attack and throttling

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Just wanted to understand how Azure AD handles DDOs attack and throttling. Does it uses it's own Azure DDoS service? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/ddos-protection/#overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Azure AD uses it own Azure DDos protection and even you can live check the Azure DDos protection [status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status) of every regions

Every property in Azure is protected by Azure's infrastructure DDoS (Basic) Protection at no additional cost. The scale and capacity of the globally deployed Azure network provides defense against common network-layer attacks through always-on traffic monitoring and real-time mitigation. DDoS Protection Basic requires no user configuration or application changes. DDoS Protection Basic helps protect all Azure services, including PaaS services like Azure DNS.

For more please refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-overview) :